# How to fix 'no module named actionlib_tutorials.msg error when going through the actionlib ros tutorials

Tags: ros, ros-melodic

I'm going through the actionlib tutorials and I'm getting this error with the example python script:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/leonard/catkin_ws/src/actionlib_tutorials/simple_action_servers/fibonacci_server.py", line 7, in <module>
import actionlib_tutorials.msg
ImportError: No module named actionlib_tutorials.msg
```

This is very confusing because actionlib_tutorials does have an 'msg' file.

I am using ros melodic in singularity

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have followed the [section on creating the action messages](http://wiki.ros.org/actionlib_tutorials/Tutorials/SimpleActionServer%28ExecuteCallbackMethod%29#Creating_the_Action_Messages) in the C++ tutorial before doing the Python tutorial. You especially need to do the `catkin_make` step at the end of that section or the Python module for the messages won't be created.